# Can "sized up" be used when a person is looking at the area in front of him and thinking about it and analysing it in his mind?

Tags: phrase-usage, verbs, vocabulary, phrases

If I am looking at a clearing in a forest where I want to set up my tent for the night, can I "size up" the clearing? Consider the sentence - "I sized up the clearing in the forest..."

Answer (score 2):

Yes, certainly. It would mean you *examined* the place (but more critically, attentively, searchingly - you *scrutinised* it).

Answer (score 1):

I'd have to say *no* - it doesn't feel right in your context.

"Size up" may sound like it literally means to measure something for size - but it is so commonly used as an idiom in a metaphorical sense that it no longer sounds natural when using it the way you suggest. "Sizing up" has come to mean *a quick assessment or judgement, usually of a person*. It just doesn't sound right with looking at a forest clearing in order to pitch a tent.

When it comes to looking at land or terrain in particular, "survey" would be the most idiomatic.

> I surveyed the clearing in the forest.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Since you say "sizing up" has come to mean a quick assessment or judgement, usually of a person, can it be used when you see someone new and you sort of scan them to get an idea - their face, clothes, etc?

"He sized her up as she approached the podium with quick strides." - sounds okay?

Comment: @Madhur That's exactly how it used.